# Angular2 route to relative path and remove current parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have two url.

```
1. 
/service/products;sort=date

2.
/service/products/detail;pno=1
```

Now, I want to move from 1 to 2.

```
/service/products/detail;pno=1
```

When I use this code

```
<a [routerLink]="['detail', detail.pno ]">
```

browser routed to 2 succefully but 1's parameter kept like

```
/service/products;sort=date/detail;pno=1
```

How can I move to 2 from 1 by html directives but remove 1's parameters?
    /service/products/detail;pno=1

I have to relative path.
actually /service/products also not a concurrent path but 'products' is a path parameter.

Comment: Can you create plnkr for this?

Comment: OK, I am not sure but I will try to. I am a really beginner and never used plnkr.

Comment: Goto http://plnkr.co/edit/JbDKtzfENqBI55I8PYoM?p=preview , Fork and start editing